# how is the data encoded when it is sent from amfphp to flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, encoding, deserialization, amfphp

How is the data serialized/encoded when sent to flash?

or, 'how is the data encoded when it is sent from amfphp to flash?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. It turns out AMF is a format - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format

using these hex values

```
Undefined - 0x00
Null - 0x01
Boolean False - 0x02
Boolean True - 0x03
Integer - 0x04
Double - 0x05
String - 0x06
XML - 0x07
Date - 0x08
Array - 0x09
Object - 0x0A
XML End - 0x0B
ByteArray - 0x0C
```

there is a library here that can desierialize 
https://github.com/pwalczyszyn/amf-message-deserializer that converts it to an object readable by as3

Answer (score 0):

In as3, JSON is used to encode/decode data from php to flash or vice-versa. You'll be needing [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) to use this feature.